# How to highlight list item inside a nested list in MudBlazor?

Tags: mudblazor

I want to be able to highlight a `<MudListItem>` inside a `<NestedList>` using the property `SelectedValue`

This sample code works like a charm

```
<MudList Clickable="true" SelectedValue="3">
    <MudListItem Value="1">Item 1</MudListItem>
    <MudListItem Value="2">Item 2</MudListItem>
    <MudListItem Value="3">Item 3</MudListItem> <-- cool! it is highlighted
</MudList>
```

However, in this markup, the selected value doesn't get highlighted

```
<MudList Clickable="true" SelectedValue="3">
    <MudListItem Text="GroupOne" InitiallyExpanded="true">
        <NestedList>
            <MudListItem Value="1">Item 1</MudListItem>
            <MudListItem Value="2">Item 2</MudListItem>
        </NestedList>
    </MudListItem>
    <MudListItem Text="GroupTwo" InitiallyExpanded="true">
        <NestedList>
            <MudListItem Value="3">Item 3</MudListItem> <-- nope, doesn't get highlighted
            <MudListItem Value="4">Item 4</MudListItem>
        </NestedList>
    </MudListItem>
</MudList>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the `MudList` instance isn't able to see the items due to them being wrapped in a `NestedList`.

As a workaround, you can try highlighting an item programmatically, based on the `SelectedValue`, by assigning a `SelectedItem` value, when the component is first rendered.

### Example:

https://try.mudblazor.com/snippet/cOQQaWvOqBoBxsAf

```
<MudList @ref=@list Clickable="true" SelectedValue="3">
    <MudListItem Text="GroupOne" InitiallyExpanded="true">
        <NestedList>
            <MudListItem @ref=@items[0] Value="1">Item 1</MudListItem>
            <MudListItem @ref=@items[1] Value="2">Item 2</MudListItem>
        </NestedList>
    </MudListItem>
    <MudListItem Text="GroupTwo" InitiallyExpanded="true">
        <NestedList>
            <MudListItem @ref=@items[2] Value="3">Item 3</MudListItem>
            <MudListItem @ref=@items[3] Value="4">Item 4</MudListItem>
        </NestedList>
    </MudListItem>
</MudList>

@code {
    private MudList list;
    private MudListItem[] items = new MudListItem[4];

    protected override void OnAfterRender(bool firstRender)
    {
        if (firstRender)
        {
            var itemToSelect = items.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Value.Equals(list.SelectedValue));
            
            if (itemToSelect != null)
            {
                list.SelectedItem = itemToSelect;
                StateHasChanged();
            }
        }
    }
}
```